# Dependent source circuit find voltage

Tags: voltage, current, voltage-source, nodal-analysis

Suppose we have this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYoQqy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How to do nodal analysis for this circuit?

Is it $$5-\frac{5-V_{A}}{2}-V_{A} = 0$$?

or $$5-\frac{5-V_{A}}{2} - 2 \frac{5-V_{A}}{2} = 0$$

**EDIT**

By

Comment: Notice that 5 has a unit of voltage and (5 - Va)/2 will have a unit of current. So you cannot subtract current from a voltage (subtract apples from bananas).

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to introduce \$I_M\$ into the fray or you'll just get 0 = 0 and that helps nobody: -

$$5 = 2\cdot I_M + V_A$$

Where \$V_A = 2\cdot I_M\$ (as per the dependent source) so: -

$$5 = 2\cdot I_M + 2\cdot I_M$$

And, \$I_M=1.25\text{ amps}\$ and \$V_A = 2.5\text{ volts}\$. Sanity check: -

[image]